# error: nothing to repeat at position 0 using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Given a censored string and a string of the censored vowels, return the
original uncensored string.

```
import re

def uncensor(string1, string2):
  # Use a regular expression to find all the asterisks in string1
  asterisks = re.findall(r'\*?', string1)

  # Replace each asterisk with the corresponding character from string2
  for i, asterisk in enumerate(asterisks):
    string1 = re.sub(asterisk, string2[i], string1, count=1)

  return string1

uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*", "eeioeo") #➞ "Where did my vowels go?"
```

I got the following error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-fee597a500f6> in <module>
     11   return string1
     12 
---> 13 uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*", "eeioeo") #➞ "Where did my vowels go?"

6 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    666                 item = None
    667             if not item or item[0][0] is AT:
--> 668                 raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
    669                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
    670             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:

error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

I tried pattern r'*+*' , r'*', r'*+' but I am always getting error.

i was expecting this

`uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*", "eeioeo")` ➞ "Where did my vowels go?"

Comment: The error comes from the `re.sub` call where `asterisk` is just a `*`, and not a `\*`. I don't understand why you even use `re.sub` there. It can just be `string1 = string1.replace('*', string2[i], 1)`

Comment: What @Tomerikoo said; you actually never need `re`: just loop on string2 ( `for vowel in string2: string1 = string1.replace('*', vowel, 1)`

Comment: @Swifty You were also right. The use of `?` creates a list full of empty strings, together with the unescaped asterisk in the `re.sub` that was the problem

Comment: Yes; after seing your comment, I had a doubt and removed mine :) I found out later there were 2 errors, and each of us pointed one :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank You! Yes, you were right I was unnecessarily using re. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Swifty Yes, you were right I was unnecessarily using re.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current approach has multiple problems, with the function logic and the regex usage.  I would go about this by doing a regex replacement on `\*` with a callback function.  In the callback we can pop one vowel from the list of replacement vowels, for each `*` occurence.

```py
import re

def uncensor(string1, string2):
    chars = list(string2)
    return re.sub(r'\*', lambda m: chars.pop(0), string1)

output = uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*", "eeioeo")
print(output)  # Where did my vowels go
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems here. First of all the use of `?` in the search pattern is wrong. If you inspect your results, you will see that `asterisks` is:

```
['', '', '*', '', '*', '', '', '*', '', '', '', '', '', '', '*', '', '*', '', '', '', '', '*', '']
```

So it should just be `r"\*"`.

Secondly, in your replacement loop, the `asterisk` is the actual match from the string, so your pattern becomes `*`, which is invalid.
You can do [`re.escape(asterisk)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape it.

Lastly, you don't even need `re` here as all your regex gives you is a list of asterisks. The whole task can be done with [string operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```py
def uncensor(string1, string2):
  # Replace each asterisk with the corresponding character from string2
  for repl in string2:
    string1 = string1.replace('*', repl, 1)

  return string1

uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*", "eeioeo") #➞ "Where did my vowels go?"
```